# Why is it not possible to provide both color and decoration in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to set a colour to a container and a different one to it's decoration but the compiler says it's impossible

```
Container(
  width: 110,
  height: 110,
  color: Colors.red,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: appColor,         // personalized colour
    border: Border.all(width: 8),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90)),
  ),                    
),
```

Comment: Setting both Decoration and Color doesn't make sense as Color can be set on Decoration (which override the original Color). So, at this point "framework" says which of those two i should I use??

Answer (score 0):

The **color** and **decoration** arguments **cannot both be supplied**, since it would potentially result in the decoration drawing over the background color. To supply a decoration with a color, use:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)
```

that because in **container.dart** there is assert:

```
assert(color == null || decoration == null,
         'Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\n'
         'To provide both, use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".',
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they serve two distinct functions, adding `color` and `decoration` to a widget at the same time is not feasible with Flutter.

`Color` is a straightforward way to specify a widget's background colour or text color. It is a fundamental characteristic that may be changed on the widget itself.

In contrast, `decoration` is a more complicated attribute that enables you to provide a widget several aesthetic effects, such a border, a background picture, or a gradient. It is a more complex attribute than a mere colour and calls for additional setting.

There could be issues when you provide a widget both `colour` and `decoration`. For instance, if you set a background `color` first with `color` and then an image with decoration, the picture will cover the `color` and make it invisible.

So, You should pick either colour or decoration to define the visual look of your widget, depending on your needs, to avoid conflicts and guarantee that your widgets are presented as intended.